# Identifying 4 coil 2 wire motor and run it from DC

Tags: motor, identification

Motor has 2 wires and 4 coils connected in series.
Rotating part with permanent magnet ring with 2 N and 2 S poles.

It does not rotate when DC-powered.

I want to make it rotating somehow without much requirements in torque and speed.
I prefer DC power. And if this is AC motor may be some simple alternating using H-bridge (L298).

[image]
[image]

Comment: The motor looks to me like it is a brushless DC (BLDC) motor of the type that is often called an "outrunner" because the stationary part (stator) is in the center and the rotating part (rotor) is on the outside. It looks like the rotor is in the background. It has a permanent magnet ring rotor that surrounds the stator. The coils need to be energized in sequence to make the motor operate. You should find a detailed explanation of BLDC motors to learn how to design the required electronic controller.

Comment: As you can see there are only 2 wires so coils connect to it in series

Comment: I think there is something missing or something that can not be seen in the photo. More than two connections are required determine which way the motor will rotate. I suppose the blower could have flat blades so that it doesn't matter which way the motor turns.

Comment: @User1329019 Your motor is a single phase, synchronous, permanent magnet AC (AKA brushless DC) motor, probably with single hall effect sensor feedback. Brushless motors aren't always three phase, you will also find single phase (fans), two phase (fans, stepper motors), three phase (general purpose) and sometimes even more phases (niche applications). You need to employ the original driver or roll your own single phase synchronous motor controller.

Answer (score 1):

As the label say, this is out of a Ricool-3 blower.
See [**catalog here**](https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjTqaCSmqHSAhVCi5QKHRGqBGMQFggkMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rittal.com%2Fimf%2Fnone%2F5_3994%2FRittal_Rittal_Electronic_Enclosure_System_5_3994&usg=AFQjCNEFNmSP-WbpzBoKoY6gPffsox7CyA&sig2=A9-I3d9IuBiJWnLK5VDHUg) pages 56 & 57.

The original blower has the controller inbuilt and is speed controllable using PWM. However, it has a 3 x 10 30 pin connector with a host of uncertain or outright inscrutable functions.

Do you have the complete original unit?

If you do not have the original controller then a simple reversing polarity drive and suitable hall rotation sensor(s) will work - as described below.

---

There is probably either an external rotation sensor or the driver IC that controlled the motor has back-EMF sensing.  If you have the original control electronics you can probably use them to make the job much easier.

If the motor has only 2 wires connecting the stator then it is a crude but clever BLDCM (brushless DC motor) implementation.

When voltage of one polarity is applied the 4 coils have magnetic polarity of NSNS. When the applied voltage polarity is reversed the magnets will swap to SNSN. Initially a rotor permanent magnet above or near a pole of the same polarity N-N or S-S will be repelled. and a rotor magnet above or near a pole of opposite polarity S-N or N-S will be attracted. Once the rotor position has mechanically stabilised so that all rotor magnets are aligned with poles of opposite polarity, reversing the applied voltage will make the rotor move 1/4 turn to again cause stability. If, as the rotor just about reaches the new position, the applied voltage polarity is again reversed the rotor will "continue on its way" due to inertia, 'heading for' the next stable point which is now 1/4 turn away. If voltage reversals occur every 1/4 turn the rotor will "chase" the moving magnetic field.
As the chase continues the rotor will move faster and the time between 1/4 turns will decrease. The controller needs to "know" when the rotor is approaching the latest table position so that it can change voltage polarity.
This is achieved with a sensor or sensors - either external hall sensors or by sensing the induced "back EMF voltages).

The existing controller will include the means of sensing. Using the controller if available may be the easiest approach. If it is an integral part of a microcontroller then this may not be possible. In that case, adding a Hall sensor to detect rotor position and switching coil polarity based on the result would probably be the easiest approach. A single sensor will not allow rotation direction to be controlled. Two hall sensors offset from each other by a fraction of 1/4 of a turn will allow direction to be detected and so controlled. eg If S1 (sensor 1) & S2 outputs are low then whichever goes high 1st shows which way the rotor is turning. Simple logic can be used to change the drive signal if direction is incorrect.

**______________________**

**Test Circuit:**

The L298 IC [datasheet here](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/82/cc/3f/39/0a/29/4d/f0/CD00000240.pdf/files/CD00000240.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000240.pdf) is a dual half bridge driver IC that could be used to make a test circuit.

Using the diagram below, application of a 0V/5V square wave at Vin will produce a square wave toggling motor drive signal at Vout.
The IC needs 5V on V22 (pin 9 in diagram) and motor voltage on Vs (pin 4).
This circuit has NO feedback signal so will not drive the motor well but should show that it is working.

[image]

The inverter is one portion of any 5V capable inverter

Apply 5V to Vss, probably OK to try 5V to Vs initially, and apply a 0/5V square wave at say 100 Hz to Vin.
Turn on the supply - the motor will "jiggle" and may or may not turn. Spin the shaft by hand (with due care) and the motor will quite possible run at about one turn per square wave cycle.

You can buy the bare IC from [eg Digikey for $US4.42](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/stmicroelectronics/L298N/497-1395-5-ND/585918) OR  [**a complete assembled PCB for $US1.75 wit free shipping](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Stepper-Motor-Drive-Controller-Board-Module-L298N-Dual-H-Bridge-for-Arduino-/331838126046?hash=item4d4317f7de:g:IEkAAOSw1DtXGlDY) from China via ebay [!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!]

$US1.75, free shipping:

[image]

Comment: `A single sensor will not allow rotation direction to be controlled` Only if the sensor is mounted at a multiple of 180 (electrical) degrees relative to the stator windings. Then you don't have to use two sensors in a quadrature encoder- like configuration, as you can measure the relative timing between the H-bridge output and the sensor input.

Comment: If there was no rotation sensing in the electronics, some asymmetry in the magnetic circuit, aka "shaded pole" could provide bias to start it in the correct direction.  But I'm not seeing any asymmetry in the pics so I think you're right ... single phase AC with some trick to start it in the right direction. You may see it rotate the wrong way for a quarter turn on startup, with the original electronics

Comment: Thank you. I have complete unit in unknown but non working condition. I will try

Answer (score 0):

This type of motor is commonly used in small fans.  It is a single-phase brushless dc motor, as such it requires an electronic controller to perform the function of a commutator, which is to switch the direction of the current in the stator (the armature in this case) as the rotor (field) turns.

These single phase motors have positions where the field poles are aligned with the stator poles, where there is zero torque.  When running, inertia keeps the rotor moving through these positions, but when stopped in these positions starting can be problematic.  To prevent stopping in these positions, the stator laminations are not perfectly cylindrical, but are shaped such that reluctance torque will pull the rotor away from these dead spots and into a position where the motor can produce torque and can start reliably.

A controller for this type of motor is pretty simple.  As you suggested, the winding terminals are connected across an H-bridge.  The H-bridge is controlled such that one side of the winding is connected to the positive supply and the other side is connected negative to apply voltage to the winding.  At the commutation time, this is reversed to apply voltage in the opposite direction.

I'm not familiar with this particular motor, but surely it had a provision to mount a hall effect device to detect the magnet flux.  This sensor would be located between the stator poles, so that it switches at the zero torque positions. (In practice, it can be advanced a little to provide an earlier commutation to compensate for stator current rise and fall time).  The output of this sensor is used to control the H-bridge.

That's all there is to the simplest controller.  Typically, a current sensing circuit is added to protect the bridge by limiting the stator current.  This can be incorporated into a circuit to PWM the lower 'on' transistor to provide a speed ramp and/or to vary the operating speed.